# unixODBC and Electron JS, ODBC works in development but not in production build

Tags: electron, unixodbc, pervasive

I'm working on an Electron JS app using electron-react-boilerplate and I'm using node-odbc to connect to a PervasiveSQL database. All was working as expected in terms of being able to CRUD on target Pervasive tables until I packaged it to a production build and proceeded to test.

The error I'm receiving on attempting to connect:

`[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.dylib' : file not found`

As I said, I don't receive this error when running in development using the included default electron-react-boilerplate script below:

`cross-env START_HOT=1 node -r @babel/register ./internals/scripts/CheckPortInUse.js && cross-env START_HOT=1 yarn start-renderer-dev`

Another note, not sure if relevant but if I start the *.app using `lldb` it works as expected.

I've included relevant information below, based on other similar related posts I've found:

Lib exists:

```
ls -l /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 psql  pvsw      18 Jan 30 15:51 /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.dylib -> libodbcci.dylib.13
lrwxr-xr-x  1 psql  pvsw      29 Jan 30 15:51 /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.dylib.13 -> libodbcci.dylib.13.31.015.000
-rwxr-xr--@ 1 psql  pvsw  826256 Dec 15 17:38 /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.dylib.13.31.015.000
```

unixODBC Setup:

```
$ cat /usr/local/psql/etc/odbc.ini
[ODBC Data Sources]
GLOBAL_TST=Pervasive ODBC Interface

[GLOBAL_TST]
Driver=/usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.dylib
Description=Pervasive ODBC Interface: ***.***.**.*:1583/GLOBALTST
DBQ=GLOBALTST
ServerName=***.***.**.*:1583
UID=*******
PWD=*******
OpenMode=0
PvTranslate=
$ isql global_tst -v
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

~/.zshrc

```
export PVSW_ROOT=/usr/local/psql
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PVSW_ROOT/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH

if [ $(uname -s) = "Darwin" ]
then
    export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PVSW_ROOT/lib64:$PVSW_ROOT/bin:/usr/lib
    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
else
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PVSW_ROOT/lib:$PVSW_ROOT/lib64:$PVSW_ROOT/bin:/usr/$
fi

export MANPATH=$PVSW_ROOT/man:$MANPATH
export BREQ=$PVSW_ROOT/lib
export LD_BIND_NOW=1

...
```

Comment: Is the production build on the same machine as the test build? Is it running as the same user?  This sounds like a configuration issue with being able to access the Pervasive ODBC driver.

Comment: yes, tried launching the app from the same terminal I built it in using `sudo -u <my-user-name> /Applications/<app-name>.app/Contents/MacOS/<app-name>` just to be sure. also tried changing ownership of the entire `/usr/local/psql` dir, and changed permissions to `777`

Comment: I agree though, most likely a configuration issue. What is different about starting the app using lldb? I've never used it previously, but find it peculiar that it runs fine when using that to start it.

Comment: @dirkenstocks did you ever figure out what was causing this? Running into the same issue where odbc works fine running in dev mode, but not in the built app.

Comment: @MasterOdin I did eventually get it working, and boo on me for not posting back here because at this point I can't remember the exact specifics. Trying to jog my memory, I want to say the topics discussed in [this](https://github.com/w1nk/node-odbc/issues/107)  thread were related to the issue I was experiencing. Also, i remember using the build dependencies in [this](https://github.com/w1nk/node-odbc/issues/100#issuecomment-251979450) comment in particular.